# Add to vector within a map

Tags: clojure

Say I have a node with the following structure

```
(def root {:name "-" :children [{:name "A" :children []}]})
```

I want to add a second child to the root node.

```
{:name "B" :children []}
```

I thought I could use `update`

e.g.

```
(update root :children #(conj (:children %) {:name "B" :children []}))
```

However, this results in:

```
{:name "-", :children ({:name "B", :children []})}
```

I've lost "A", even though I used `conj` ?
Also the `:children` vector is now a list...

What am I doing wrong here? Am I using the entirely wrong function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I don't need the (:children %) in the function that adds the child. I should have been using

```
(update root :children #(conj % {:name "B" :children []}))
```

Looks like the function expects the original value for :children to be passed in, not the whole map :)

Comment: You can actually simplify this to: `(update root :children conj {:name "B" :children []})`